Overprint not working with images when using braces
The following code works as expected, where two images appear on two different slides in the same location:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{Test}
    \begin{overprint}
      \onslide<1>\includegraphics{pictures/test1.png}
      \onslide<2>\includegraphics{pictures/test2.png}
    \end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

However, if I add braces after the onslide command, it no longer works:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{Test}
    \begin{overprint}
      \onslide<1>{\includegraphics{pictures/test1.png}}
      \onslide<2>{\includegraphics{pictures/test2.png}}
    \end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Why is this? For context, I am including braces because I want to be able to use \onslide commands outside of the overprint environment. a MWE of my ultimate goal is:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{itemize}
  \onslide<1> {\item Slide 1}
  \onslide<2> {\item Slide 2}
  \end{itemize}
    \begin{overprint}
      \onslide<1>{\includegraphics{pictures/test1.png}}
      \onslide<2>{\includegraphics{pictures/test2.png}}
    \end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

The two separate instances of onslide don't seem to work unless I include braces, but doing so causes the overprint to cease working.

The behaviour of \onslide is different if there is an argument or not. To quote the beamer user guide:

The behavior of this command depends on whether the optional argument ⟨text⟩ is given or not (note that the optional argument is given in normal braces, not in square brackets). If present, the ⟨modifier⟩ can be either a+or a*.
[...]
If a ⟨text⟩ argument is present, \onslide (without a ⟨modifier⟩) is mapped to \uncover, \onslide+ is mapped to \visible, and \onslide* is mapped to \only.

This means, that if you want to use an argument and want the argument not to occupy space, then you should use \onslide*.
(personally I find it much easier to directly use \only{}, \uncover{} etc., then one directly knows what it does from the name)
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{itemize}[<only@+>]
  \item Slide 1
  \item Slide 2
  \end{itemize}
    \begin{overprint}
      \onslide*<1>{\includegraphics[page=1]{example-image-duck}}
      \onslide*<2>{\includegraphics[page=2]{example-image-duck}}
    \end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


